# How to check if `enable-bracketed-paste` is on or off in Bash?

Tags: bash, shell

I have `set enable-bracketed-paste off` in `~/.inputrc`, but it still gets enabled from time to time.

To help figure out when this is happening, I want a short script to check if it is off or on, but much googling and chatGPT haven't been any help.

Surely there must be a way to read values set with `set some-option`? `shopt` seemed promising (new to me), but again a dead end.

```
$ shopt -s enable-bracketed-paste
bash: shopt: enable-bracketed-paste: invalid shell option name
```

`echo "$(set)" | grep "enable-bracketed-paste"` finds nothing whether  it's on or off.

Comment: It's not a shell option; it's a Readline variable. Readline is a standalone library that was refactored out of `bash`, and it continues to be documented in the `bash` man page.

Comment: Aside: `echo "$(set)" ` why `echo`? Just do `set | grep ...`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`shopt` doesn't have much to do with inputrc, try :

```
bind -V | grep enable-bracketed-paste
```

Comment: I ended up going with `bind -v 2> /dev/null | grep enable-bracketed-paste` to squelch the bind warning.

Comment: That's even better!